# npm err! fibers@4.0.2 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js` when installing Vuetify in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I created a Nuxt app using `npx create-nuxt-app`

but when running dev server `npm run dev` the following error occurs

```
 ╭──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                                  │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                             │
   │                                                                  │
   │   Error: Module `@nuxtjs/vuetify` not found. Please ensure       │
   │   `@nuxtjs/vuetify` is in `devDependencies` and installed.       │
   │   HINT: During build step, for npm/yarn, `NODE_ENV=production`   │
   │   or `--production` should NOT be used.                          │
   │                                                                  │
   ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! src@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the src@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

when I tried running `npm install` it give a error(this msg was taken from npm-cache log)

```
781 verbose stack Error: fibers@4.0.2 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
781 verbose stack Exit status 1
781 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
781 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:321:20)
781 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
781 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
781 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
781 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
782 verbose pkgid fibers@4.0.2
783 verbose cwd H:\_medical_reports_(_arkham_asylum_)\Others\Code\Web\vscodegit\travelersofbanagladesh\client\src
784 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
785 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
786 verbose node v13.8.0
787 verbose npm  v6.13.6
788 error code ELIFECYCLE
789 error errno 1
790 error fibers@4.0.2 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
790 error Exit status 1
791 error Failed at the fibers@4.0.2 install script.
791 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
792 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

it is a brand new Nuxt app and I haven not touched any file

I also tried creating Nuxt app using Vue cli and it worked(without vuetify) and when tried installing vuetify it gave similar error

I am using Vue 2.9.6 fresh installed today and Node 13.8.0

Answer (score 2):

`node` version 14 causes this problem when creating nuxt app with vuetify on windows machines. the only known solution for this is at this moment, is to downgrade `node` to version 12 LTS.

References:

[nuxt/create-nuxt-app](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/517)

[nuxt-community/vuetify-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/345)

EDIT: [link for all node releases downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)