# The required version of sdk is not found - NuxtJS sass installation

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, bulma

I have created new project using Nuxt. And as I was trying the command:

```
npm install --save-dev sass sass-loader@10 fibers
```

It have generated a lot of errors but the one line of error that I understand is this:

> npm ERR! C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\PC-Admin\Development\vue\bulma-project\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]

I tried to locate my sdk on my pc and it showed like this:

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my problem by downgrading my node version to node v.12. I referred to this [npm err! fibers@4.0.2 install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812606/npm-err-fibers4-0-2-install-node-build-js-nodejs-build-js-when-installin)

I think the main problem is with the installation with fibers on the latest version of node, so what I did based on what I found was to downgrade my node.